# onlistitemclick after filtering the listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am retreiving 20 names from an sqlite database and displaying them in the form of `listview`. They are unsorted. I use `filter` and sort them alphabetically so that I avoid unnecesary scrolling. I have an `edittext` too. When I type a key, it matches the `listitems` and filters the list. Each `listitem` has a respective text with it,

The problem now here is, when I sort and filter, the position of the `listitem` changes. When I click on that, it displays its current positions text and the `listitem`'s text.

For example: I have a 3 DB entries

```
ROWID NAME       DESCRPTION
1    RASHMI   I AM FRM INDIA
2    RICHA    I AM FROM USA
3    STELLA   I AM FROM CANADA.
```

My list view displays only the `NAME` column. Now when I press `S` in the `edittext`, `STELLA` comes up from position 3 to position 1. When I click on that `listitem`, it displays `I AM FROM INDIA` instead of `I AM FROM CANADA`. Every action is taking place from SQLite DB.

Answer (score 0):

post your adapter code.

if you are changing the cursor on the adapter as you probably are. be sure to get the cursor from the adapter by calling

```
    Cursor c = adapter.getCursor()
c.moveToPosition(position);
String description = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DESCRIPTION"));
```

the key thing is to move the cursor to the desired position in the list. also be sure you are using the attached cursor to the listView not a previously saved instance or from your first query when you were assigning it to the adapter.